# How Does Mega.co.nz detect your user agent?

Tags: browser, user-agent

how does mega detect your user agent? Javascript? It seems to be able to bypass Chrome UA Spoofer, and doesn't allow a chrome that isn't up to date.

Comment: It could possibly be using some recent chrome api. If it tries to use SomeFunctionOnlyInChrome29andAbove() whatever you spoof in 26 won't help.

Comment: Thanks. But I still wish I could access Mega in Chrome 21. I use a version that I've blocked from updating (I've lost a few months of bookmarks in the days of the version 11-14 updates).